# How to serialize boost::dynamic_bitset?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

**How to serialize a class with a  boost::dynamic_bitset member?**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/bitset.hpp>
#include <sstream>

class A
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> x;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int){
        ar & x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << a;
    return 0;
}
```

**Compiling gives an error (boost 1.57)**

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:38,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:31,
                 from dynamic_bitset_setial.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In static member function ‘static void boost::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive, T = boost::dynamic_bitset<>]’:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:69:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive, T = boost::dynamic_bitset<>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:9:   instantiated from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive, T = boost::dynamic_bitset<>]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:148:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive, T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&, const void*) const [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive, T = boost::dynamic_bitset<>]’
dynamic_bitset_setial.cpp:25:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘class boost::dynamic_bitset<>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dynamic_bitset<>` is not serializable, as you've found out (`std::bitset<N>` is different type).

Not to worry, though, you can add it without too much effort:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template <typename Ar, typename Block, typename Alloc>
        void save(Ar& ar, dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> const& bs, unsigned) {
            size_t num_bits = bs.size();
            std::vector<Block> blocks(bs.num_blocks());
            to_block_range(bs, blocks.begin());

            ar & num_bits & blocks;
        }

    template <typename Ar, typename Block, typename Alloc>
        void load(Ar& ar, dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& bs, unsigned) {
            size_t num_bits;
            std::vector<Block> blocks;
            ar & num_bits & blocks;

            bs.resize(num_bits);
            from_block_range(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), bs);
            bs.resize(num_bits);
        }

    template <typename Ar, typename Block, typename Alloc>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& bs, unsigned version) {
            split_free(ar, bs, version);
        }

} }
```

This works e.g. **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d40f07152d44c9a9)**

```
int main() {
    A a;
    for (int i=0; i<128; ++i)
        a.x.resize(11*i, i%2);

    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << a;
    }
    std::cout << ss.str();
    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        A b;
        ia >> b;

        assert(a.x == b.x);
    }
}
```

Note that if you can't afford to copy the blocks vector, it's equally easy to add serialization directly on the `m_bits` level, but that requires intrusive changes (friend access required at a minimum).

Such a thing would easily be added to boost in a pull request.

### Update [added that pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31015623/85371)

Comment: I've added the pull request I described. I figured it was clean enough and useful enough

Comment: Using your code to serialize dynamic_bitset, I am serializing to a text_iarchive and the contents of the file are surprising to me. I have created a bitset of length 454 and filled it with random values (0 or 1). When I look at the contents of the file, I see: `22 serialization::archive 12 0 0 454 8 0 13498754571592366336 199811248968146936
0 8917879989572726124 17597677761915498957 13906573370107724280 1703115579025708
5578 2950082248053176559 63`. Shouldn't I expect to see a list of the bits?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't expect that. Serialization is for transfer. I think the OP was after (efficient) binary serialization anyways, see the other answer for the best you can do. If you _want_ the bits, just write it like that: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4a05bfe79447dfb)**. Or, you know, just write to `std::cout` using `operator<<`, because you're _presenting_ in a readable way, not just wire-transfer encoding.

Comment: @DavidDoria ^ I forgot to plink you on that one

Comment: it worked fine so I figured that was the case - I guess I was just curious how those numbers are representing a bitset?

Comment: @DavidDoria It should be pretty obvious looking at the serialization code. It's just groups of bits interpreted as integers. (Next time you could ask what you wanted - saves me the time of demonstrating the alternative that you don't even need)

Comment: Thank you, it was nice to see the alternative as well.

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and **[filed the pull request](https://github.com/boostorg/dynamic_bitset/pull/14)** to add Serialization support to Boost Dynamic Bitset

> Serialization using the public interface isn't optimal as `to_block_range()`/`from_block_range()` require copying of `m_bits` (and subsequent `resize()`).
>
> I added a generic implementation to Boost Dynamic Bitset. The changes merge cleanly against develop or master (1_58_0).
>
> ### Changes
>
> Implementation added with
>
> - minimal intrusiveness, only a nested friend (`class serialization_impl;`) has been forward declared to "key-hole" the required friend access through
> - This class, as well as the actual ADL hook for Boost Serialization are implemented in a separate header (`dynamic_bitset/serialization.hpp`, similar to other boost libraries with serialization support).
> - This means that zero dependencies on Boost Serialization stuff exists unless `boost/dynamic_bitset/serialization.hpp` is actually included
> - Zero copy is achieved (leveraging `std::vector<Block>`'s builtin support in Boost Serialization)
>
> ### Tests
>
> The second commit in the pull request adds tests for this feature. I'm not sure how to add the `dyn_bitset_unit_tests5.cpp` to the Jamfile. I suppose something else must be done to ensure linking to Boost System and Boost Serialization. I have run the tests myself using a simple wrapper:
>
> ```cpp
> #include <modular-boost/libs/dynamic_bitset/dyn_bitset_unit_tests5.cpp>
>
> int main() {
>     test_main(0, nullptr);
> }
> ```
>
> Which can then be compiled and run with e.g.
>
> ```
> g++ main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_serialization && ./a.out
> ```
>
> No output means no errors.

Comment: There's no risk the dynamic-bitset will explode using this serialization implementation?

Comment: Huh. Why. I've not seen classes explode. And the implementation is not too complex. I think it's sound. What makes you ask this, @MMA?

Comment: If dynamic-bitset takes 10GB in memory, the serialized object will also be 10GB?

Comment: Roughly yes (assuming binary archives). And in such a case you ***will*** want to use the patch version (see the pull request) because it is zero copy enabled.

Comment: Why is not added to the library yet? I'm eyeballing 1.60 and have not spotted it.

Comment: @MatrixAndrew You should probably ask the library maintainers

Comment: [and it's merged into trunk!](https://github.com/boostorg/dynamic_bitset/commit/d644c83b137b5eae5aa0d5b350d2861c19b45f63)