# How to use Zero-copy sendmsg/Receive in Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, boost-asio, zero-copy

I am using Boost.Asio,
I want to improve my system by using Zero-copy sendmsg/Receive.
Can I use Zero-copy sendmsg/Receive in Boost.Asio?
Could you give me how to use them if I can use them?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of several mentioned in an answer below, but it is certainly not unfocused, except maybe to those who just don't know anything about the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, you can only if your in-memory representation is identical to the on-the-wire one.

See the answers here, which do an excellent job of describing how e.g. Cap'n Proto achieves this:

- [Do cereal and Boost Serialization use zero-copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801826/do-cereal-and-boost-serialization-use-zero-copy)

Also compare:

- [TCP Zero copy using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601331/tcp-zero-copy-using-boost/25602502#25602502)

And on creating memory-mappable representations of advanced C++ data structures so that they can be mapped on-the-wire:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.making_ipc_easy.managed_memory_segments_intro, specifically about `basic_managed_heap_memory` and `basic_managed_external_buffer`
- I have a gazillion examples on this site which show how to use such managed memory segments, but usually focused on `managed_mapped_file` and `managed_shared_memory` which have the exact same feature set, so you can use these with the previous managed heap segments in the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+interprocess+allocator