# Serialize boost::bimap with boost::dynamic_bitset as key value pair

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset, boost-bimap

I am interested to serialize a `boost::bimap` containing `boost::dynamic_bitset` so that I can save that and load back when needed. I have made an attempt to do that but I get many errors. The code that I have with me is as below.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_multiset_of.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>


namespace std {
    template <typename Block, typename Alloc>
    struct hash<boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> > {

        using bitset_type = boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>;
        using block_type = typename bitset_type::block_type ;

        size_t operator()(boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> const& bs) const
        {
            thread_local static std::vector<block_type> block_data;
            auto blocks = bs.num_blocks();
            block_data.assign(blocks, 0);
            to_block_range(bs, block_data.begin());
            return boost::hash<std::vector<block_type>>()(block_data);
        }
    };
}


    namespace {
        template <typename Block>
        struct SerializableType {
            boost::dynamic_bitset<Block> x;
            private:
            friend class boost::serialization::access;
            template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int) {
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(x);
                }
                };
}

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
    typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<> Bitset;
    typedef boost::bimap<
    bimaps::unordered_set_of<Bitset, std::hash<Bitset>>,
    bimaps::unordered_multiset_of<Bitset, std::hash<Bitset> > > bimap_reference;
    typedef bimap_reference::value_type position;
    bimap_reference index;

int main() {
    std::string val = "1010110110101010101";
    std::string key = "10010";

    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits = boost::dynamic_bitset<> (val);
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> pos_bits = boost::dynamic_bitset<> (key);
    index.insert(position(pos_bits, bits));

    std::ofstream ofs("binaryfile");
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(index);    
    index::const_iterator iter = index.begin();    


    // first left elelemt of bimap
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> first_left = iter->left;
    const bimap_reference::left_iterator left_iter = index.left.find(first_left);
    oa << left_iter;

//  first right element of bimap
    auto pos = index.left.find(first_left);
    const bimap_reference::right_iterator right_iter = index.right.find(pos->second);
    oa << right_iter;
    std::cout <<"# done" << std::endl;
    ofs.close();


    std::cout <<"# Loading binary file ... " << std::endl;
    std::ifstream ifs("binaryfile"); // name of loading file
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> index;
    bimap_reference::left_iterator left_iter;
    ia >> left_iter;
    bimap_reference::right_iterator right_iter;
    ia >> right_iter;
    std::cout<<"# done" << std::endl;
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do it?.

**EDIT_1:**

Showing the comiler and linker setting in the `Eclispse`(because I get some errors with the answer code provided @sehe).

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT_2**

Command used on linux terminal `g++ -std=c++14 -Os -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_serialization && ./a.out`

```
Errors I get with the first answer code when tried in linux terminal and eclipse IDE.
/tmp/cc71hTC2.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::vload(boost::archive::class_name_type&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE5vloadERNS0_15class_name_typeE[_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE5vloadERNS0_15class_name_typeE]+0x1): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override(boost::archive::class_name_type&)'
/tmp/cc71hTC2.o: In function `void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost13serialization15throw_exceptionINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost13serialization15throw_exceptionINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEEvRKT_]+0x1a): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/cc71hTC2.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC2ERKS4_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS4_]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/cc71hTC2.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC1ERKS4_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS4_]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/cc71hTC2.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC2ERKS3_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS3_]+0xe): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/cc71hTC2.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC1ERKS3_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS3_]+0x14): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT 3**
 Using `g++ -std=c++14 -Os -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_serialization && ldd a.out` I get the following info

```
/tmp/ccBH8KfT.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::vload(boost::archive::class_name_type&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE5vloadERNS0_15class_name_typeE[_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE5vloadERNS0_15class_name_typeE]+0x1): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override(boost::archive::class_name_type&)'
/tmp/ccBH8KfT.o: In function `void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost13serialization15throw_exceptionINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost13serialization15throw_exceptionINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEEvRKT_]+0x1a): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/ccBH8KfT.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC2ERKS4_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS4_]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/ccBH8KfT.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC1ERKS4_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS4_]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/ccBH8KfT.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC2ERKS3_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS3_]+0xe): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
/tmp/ccBH8KfT.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception>::error_info_injector(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC1ERKS3_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_7archive17archive_exceptionEEC5ERKS3_]+0x14): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
```

Comment: Please. "when tried in linux terminal and eclipse IDE" - there's no such thing. Please specify the exact commands you run in the terminal.

Comment: @sehe `g++ -std=c++14 -Os -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_serialization && ./a.out`

Comment: That's my command line. It uses default include/library paths, so it would use the distro versions? Or maybe your prefix interferes and it does find your custom built version. Maybe not. Go check that. Use `ldd a.out` after build, use `g++ -v ...` to get verbose(r) output etc. See also LD_LIBRARY_PATH and or `-rpath` linker flags (PS your distro version is not recent enough)

Comment: If you mean to say `g++ -std=c++14 -Os -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_serialization && 1dd a.out`, then I get the same error messages. With verbose `g++ -v . . .`  I could not find any  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and or `-rpath`. My distro version is latest `(Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)`

Comment: `ldd`, not `1dd`. You "get the same error messages" - what. You realize that in `command1 && command2` command2 never runs if command1 failed, right?. By the way, that's the GCC verions, not distro version.

Comment: Kindly follow the error messages in `EDIT 3` above. I am not sure how to find distro version. Do you mean `cat /etc/*-release`, I got the following information `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial`

Comment: Thank you, after going through a very tough time I finally managed to remove the `lboost-1.58-dev` (which was the real culprit) and build the `boost1_65_1`, then It worked fine when using with -I and -L.  It takes more time to build the `bimap` approx 5 seconds for .25 million entries. Also loading the binary bimap takes more time (I think that can be a  put as a separate question "How to load binary bimap in a faster way"?)

Comment: That's awesome. Glad you got it sorted. The part of developingthat is "sys admin" related is vastly  underestimated

Comment: I'd say go for the performance question. Be sure to describe the goal, reason for serialising, reason for the choice of data structures. So we can validate the design decisions out suggest alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wow. You're not aiming for performance with that hash function.

   - you're copying all the blocks on every key/value hash (e.g. on lookup, on insert)
   - you **better** never wish to use co-routines because that thread-local static will make your life miserable

   See my BONUS section below
2. Why this awkward dance (simplified code):

   ```
   auto iter = index.begin();

   // first left element of bimap
   BS first_left = iter->left;
   Index::left_iterator left_iter = index.left.find(first_left);
   ```

   What is wrong with

   ```
   auto left_iter = index.left.begin();
   ```
3. What do you think is the validity of an iterator when serialized? (See [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules))

   ```
   oa << left_iter;
   ```

   I think loading a new datastructure from storage counts as "reallocation". Iterators or references to another datastructure are obviously meaningless here.
4. Erm. Now it's really getting confusing.

   ```
   //  first right element of bimap
   auto pos = index.left.find(first_left);
   Index::right_iterator right_iter = index.right.find(pos->second);
   ```

   You call it the "first right element", but you do something ELSE: you find the iterator corresponding to the `first_left` key (which may well be the last element on the right. Also note that since the right hand side of the bimap is `multiset_of`, there might be multiple matches and you random use the first.

   (Side note: `pos` is a useless duplication of `left_iter`'s value)
5. See 3.

   ```
   oa << right_iter;
   ```
6. Varia:

   - make sure you open the files as binary

     ```
     std::ofstream ofs("binaryfile", std::ios::binary);
     std::ifstream ifs("binaryfile", std::ios::binary);
     ```
   - why do you name a container with value-semantics `index_reference`? That's just unnecessarily confusing
   - `SerializableType` is unused
   - `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP` is meaningless for binary archives (nodes have no names in those)

### The Real Question

I suppose, the real question might have been "how do I serialize the `Bitset`s?". I'm happy to inform you I wrote the required bits in 2015: [How to serialize boost::dynamic_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006792/how-to-serialize-boostdynamic-bitset/31015623#31015623) and the pull request has been accepted into Boost [starting with version 1.64](https://github.com/boostorg/dynamic_bitset/commit/d644c83b137b5eae5aa0d5b350d2861c19b45f63).

So, you can sit back, sip your tea and include:

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/serialization.hpp>
```

*All done*.

### The BONUS Section

Since that serialization achieves a minimal-copy serialization, why not use it to power the hash function? The serialization mechanism will provide you the required private access.

I've abused serialization plumbing for `hash<>` specializations before: [Hash an arbitrary precision value (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int/30111778#30111778)

### Putting It All Together

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6559e8ccfdb3ff3d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_multiset_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/serialization.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

namespace serial_hashing { // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int
    namespace io = boost::iostreams;

    struct hash_sink {
        hash_sink(size_t& seed_ref) : _ptr(&seed_ref) {}

        typedef char         char_type;
        typedef io::sink_tag category;

        std::streamsize write(const char* s, std::streamsize n) {
            boost::hash_combine(*_ptr, boost::hash_range(s, s+n));
            return n;
        }
      private:
        size_t* _ptr;
    };

    template <typename T> struct hash_impl {
        size_t operator()(T const& v) const {
            using namespace boost;
            size_t seed = 0;
            {
                iostreams::stream<hash_sink> os(seed);
                archive::binary_oarchive oa(os, archive::no_header | archive::no_codecvt);
                oa << v;
            }
            return seed;
        }
    };
}

namespace std {
    template <typename Block, typename Alloc> struct hash<boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> >
        : serial_hashing::hash_impl<boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc> > 
    {};
} // namespace std

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
using Bitset = boost::dynamic_bitset<>;

typedef boost::bimap<
    bimaps::unordered_set_of<Bitset, std::hash<Bitset> >,
     bimaps::unordered_multiset_of<Bitset, std::hash<Bitset> > > Index;

int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    {
        std::cout << "# Writing binary file ... " << std::endl;
        Index index;
        index.insert({Bitset("10010"s), Bitset("1010110110101010101"s)});

        std::ofstream ofs("binaryfile", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << index;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "# Loading binary file ... " << std::endl;
        std::ifstream ifs("binaryfile", std::ios::binary); // name of loading file

        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);

        Index index;
        ia >> index;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
# Writing binary file ... 
# Loading binary file ...
```

No problem.

### POST SCRIPTUM

Really, save yourself trouble. Since your usage clearly indicates you do not want *unordered* semantics, just make it ordered:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/974a0ccc4360daf8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/serialization.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
using Bitset = boost::dynamic_bitset<>;

typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::set_of<Bitset>, bimaps::multiset_of<Bitset>> Index;

int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    {
        std::cout << "# Writing binary file ... " << std::endl;
        Index index;
        index.insert({Bitset("10010"s), Bitset("1010110110101010101"s)});

        std::ofstream ofs("binaryfile", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << index;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "# Loading binary file ... " << std::endl;
        std::ifstream ifs("binaryfile", std::ios::binary); // name of loading file

        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);

        Index index;
        ia >> index;
    }
}
```

Down to 36 lines, less than half the code left.

Comment: Thank you for writing in detail. `1)`  Actually, I have more than 300 million entries in the `bimap` and wanted a hash function which is efficient in terms of both time and space. I hope your code is addressing both of these. `2)` For `1` I think I need `unordered semantics` to insert into a `bimap` and faster search. `3)` I tried both of the codes in `eclipse C++` but I get errors like  `void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)` or `undefined reference to boost::serialization::singleton_module::get_lock()`

Comment: Looks to me that you link to a boost library built with different flags/compiler. (Effectively making it just a different version from the headers being used)

Comment: I have Cross G++ Compiler `g++ -std=c++17`, Cross G++ Linker `g++` with `AGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}` setting. What can I do?

Comment: How do you compile the boost libraries? (especially Boost Serialization)

Comment: `-lboost_serialization` in eclipse

Comment: That how you specify the linker option. Says nothin about how that library was compiled.

Comment: Do you mean this `-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0` it is G++ Compiler options. I have no options for `Cross G++ Linker`

Comment: Do those options match (why is std=c++17 missing suddenly)? How did you specify these options for **building** libboost_serialization.so anyways? Eclipse doesn't usually build boost every time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530399/serialize-boostbimap-with-boostdynamic-bitset-as-key-value-pair#comment82062504_47543205 - Again. Where you do get Boost from? Did you build it? With what flags? If you downloaded binaries (erm) what flags were used by the providing party?

Comment: From http://www.boost.org/users/download/, unzip by `tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_65_1.tar.bz2 ` and then `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/` , and `sudo checkinstall ./b2 install`. Is not this the way. I checked the `boost` version after this by `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` and I got
`Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1`

Comment: In that case, make sure you match their build flags. I'm not sure how to find out (I think the output is quite verbose so might include it, otherwise, look for logs), but I'm absolutely sure `-std=c++17` is **not** in their flags.

Comment: What if I reinstall boost `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`.

Comment: Then you get the old version. Or the new version unless you uninstall it. Wait, this could be happening. Perhaps you're finding parts from the distro packages (check they are not installed)

Comment: Do you feel this is suspicious `libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1)` but it should show 1.65.1 right?

Comment: No that's normal and expected: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-all-dev. Note that your GCC is also the "latest version" (supplied by your distribution!). However, it's risky that it's installed. The chance now exists that you're using headers from one version and the library from another (distro packaged vs b2 installed)

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much for your time and tireless effort. I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Just make sure you control exactly what gets included and linked. It's usually easier to learn that by doing a command line build (see the command lines at coliru) then using any kind of IDE. IDEs try to hide things and operate a lot on conventions/assumptions. It can be hard to understand what actually happens, when all you need is 1, relatively simple, command line.

Comment: Not different when running on Linux terminal, also shown in the edit above.