# Find correct Boost version installed and how to remove the old version

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I had `boost` previously installed by

```
sudo apt-get libboost-dev
sudo apt-get libboost-all-dev
```

and I think I got `boost 1.58`.

Then I needed the latest `boost` for `boost_serialization`, for that I tried installing `boost` by downloading from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/), and then the following commands.

```
tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_65_1.tar.bz2
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/
sudo checkinstall ./b2 install
```

I checked the `boost` version installed by different ways.

**First**

```
std::cout << "Using Boost "
            << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
            << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
            << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
            << std::endl;
```

Which gives `Using Boost 1.65.1`

**Second**

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
```

Which gives `libboost1.58-dev:amd64: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp`

**Third**

```
cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"
```

which displays `//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION #define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_65_1"`

**Fourth**

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
```

which displays `Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1`

Which is the difference? Do I have both the versions installed or only `1.65`?

I tried removing `1.58` by `sudo apt-get autoremove`,  but I get the same information again.

I also tried removing the old by

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
sudo apt-get autoremove package
```

and it just display the following information

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package
```

Comment: [Try `ldd` on the linked binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530399/serialize-boostbimap-with-boostdynamic-bitset-as-key-value-pair#comment82081966_47530399)

Answer (score 2):

Building and installing  the tarball is not going to update what apt thinks is installed, since you used /usr as your prefix it may well have overwritten the actual files but apt will still think the old version is installed.