# Writing and Reading boost dynamic_bitset to/from file

Tags: c++, c++11, binaryfiles, binary-data, boost-dynamic-bitset

I have searched everywhere but did not find any way to write and the read dynamic_bitset to/from file. How to make `readFromFile()` and `writeToFile()` functions for reading/writing desired bits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize boost::dynamic\_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006792/how-to-serialize-boostdynamic-bitset)

Comment: @Hasturkun I don't see any file names being passed to load and save. Why is that?

Comment: Because they don't have to. If you follow that, using boost serialization you can e.g. connect it to an ofstream (since it supports istream/ostream). Alternately, you can use that as an example without boost serialization, and implement the reading/writing based on the vector of blocks yourself.